# How to restrict use of specific attributes to specific subclasses in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got classes in a single-table inheritance hierarchy that look like this:

```
# Table name: blocks
#
#  video_name    :string  
#  text_name     :string           
#

class Block < ApplicationRecord
   ...
end

class VideoBlock < Block
end

class TextBlock < Block
end
```

The `blocks` table holds all the attributes that `Block` subclasses will use.

I'd like to specify how you can access:

- `video_name` only when you are dealing with `VideoBlock` objects
- `text_name` only when you are dealing with `TextBlock` objects

How do I do this in Ruby on Rails? (using 5.x specifically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wall these off in subclasses, you need to decide how you want to handle this. Do you want to just ignore data put in there, or do you want to freak out and catch on fire?

For catching on fire:

```
class Video
  validates :text_name,
    absence: true
end
```

That will wall off various attributes in this sub-class by raising validation exceptions.

For ignoring:

```
class Video
  def text_name=(v)
    # Ignored
  end
end
```

This is less desirable since it eats data that you might want to actually save but due to a bug are losing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating custom setters and getters:

```
class MyError < StdError; end

class Block < ApplicationRecord
  def video_name
    raise MyError unless video?
    super
  end

  def video_name=(value)
    raise MyError unless video?
    super
  end

  def video?
    self.class.name == 'VideoBlock'
  end
end
```

Comment: You `raise` *or* you `return`. Doing both looks very, very odd. The `raise` is going to pop an exeption and the `return` will never, ever run.